# Number of discontinuities in a function combining floor function and polynomial equation

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ = $\begin{cases}{ \left \lfloor {x} \right \rfloor , {-2}\leq{x} \leq{-1/2} },\\
{2x^2-1},  {-1/2}\lt{x} \leq{2}\end{cases}$

The number of points where $ f|x| $ is discontinuous has to be found out. 
Now as I see it, simply for $f(x)$, it's discontinuous at two points namely $\{-1, -1/2\}$ but with presence of absolute value function I'm confused as to argument which is negative will eventually be taken as a positive input to the function thereby taking into consideration different part of function (i.e., second one) than we would've if it were not for absolute value of input (i.e., first part of function).

What's really going on here? And secondly, was my assumption that with just $f(x)$ there would be just two points of discontinuity correct? If not then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} \lfloor x \rfloor &, -2 \le x \le - \frac12 \\
2x^2-1 & , -\frac12 < x \le 2\end{cases}$$

Then, we have

$$f(|x|)= \begin{cases} \lfloor |x| \rfloor &, -2 \le |x| \le - \frac12 \\
2|x|^2-1 & , -\frac12 < |x| \le 2\end{cases}$$

Now, let's simplify the equation above since we know that $|x| \ge 0$,

Hence we have $f(|x|)=2|x|^2-1=2x^2-1$, it is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Was my assumption that it's discontinuous at just two points without absolute value function correct? Just $f(x)$

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Just an off the topic question, what mathjax code to use for discrete set notation { } inside $ signs?

Comment: Use \{ and \} to use set notation.

Comment: My question was about {2, 3, 5, 7,....} discrete set notation mathjax code.

Comment: $\{ 2,3,5,7, \ldots \}$ can be obtained by \{ 2,3,5,7, \ldots \}